# modal pop up does not work when triggered from repeater row

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I added the following code to the repeater...

```
<input type="image" style="border-width:0" alt="Edit Reviewer Group" 
                               title="Edit Reviewer Group" tabindex="0" 
                               src='<%=ResolveUrl("~/css/images/icon_edit.png") %>' 
                               onclick='showNewRevewerGroupModalPanelNew(<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Id")%>, 
                                                                         <%#HttpUtility.HtmlEncode((string)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name"))%>);
                                                                          return false;' />
```

After the above addition...the Edit Button does not bring up the pop up box anymore...I isolated this to the "Name" column. After I include the Name column in the call to showNewRevewerGroupModalPanelNew, the modal pop up stop getting triggered when the edit icon is pressed in the repeater row....thanks for your help!

```
 function showNewRevewerGroupModalPanelNew(Id, Name) 
            {
                alert(Id);
                //$find('RevListModalPopupBehavior').show();
            }

        </script>



    <asp:Repeater ID="rptReviewerList" runat="server" OnItemCommand="_Command">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <ul class="standardList">
                                <li class="listHeader">
                                    <p class="revListTitle">Name</p>
                                    <p class="number">Number of Reviewers</p>
                                    <p class="date">Last Modified</p>
                                    <p class="edit">&nbsp;</p>
                                </li>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <li <%#Container.ItemIndex%2==0? "class='bg1'" : "" %>>
                            <p class="revListTitle"><%#HttpUtility.HtmlEncode((string)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Name"))%></p>
                            <p class="number"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ReviewerCount")%></p>
                            <p class="date"><%#String.Format("{0:d}",DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Modified"))%></p>
                            <p class="edit">
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnUpdate" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/css/images/icon_update.png"  
                                             Tooltip="Update Reviewer List" AlternateText="Update Reviewer List"  
                                             CommandName="UpdateRevList" 
                                             CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Id") %>'/>


                            <input type="image" style="border-width:0" alt="Edit Reviewer Group" 
                                   title="Edit Reviewer Group" tabindex="0" 
                                   src='<%=ResolveUrl("~/css/images/icon_edit.png") %>' 
                                   onclick='showNewRevewerGroupModalPanelNew(<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Id")%>, 
                                                                             <%#HttpUtility.HtmlEncode((string)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name"))%>);
                                                                              return false;' />              

                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtDelete" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/css/images/icon_remove.png" Tooltip="Remove Reviewer List" AlternateText="Remove Reviewer List" CommandName="DeleteRevList" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id")%>' />
                            <cc1:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="cbxDelete" runat="server" TargetControlID="imgBtDelete" ConfirmText='<%# makeDeleteText(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name").ToString()) %>'/>
                            </p>
                            </li>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                        </ul>
                        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="ibtOK"/>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="importBtn"/>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="editBtn"/>
    </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here is what Firebug tells me ReferenceError: "ABCD" is not defined..But ABCD is the value of the "Name" in the repeater row. The run time value of the input block in the repeater is:

```
<input type="image" style="border-width:0" alt="Edit Reviewer Group" 
                               title="Edit Reviewer Group" tabindex="0" 
                               src='/css/images/icon_edit.png' 
                               onclick='showNewRevewerGroupModalPanelNew(4, 
                                                                         ABCD);
                                                                          return false;' />
```

Comment: If it "stopped getting triggered" then you likely have a javascript error in there related to the data being dropped into the method. Have you looked at it with Firebug or the javascript console in your browser?

Comment: modified my post to include the error reported by Firebug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the error you indicate, I'd say that your .Net code is dumping the "Name" variable out without any kind of quotation marks to indicate it is a string, so javascript is interpretting it to be a variable name.

```
onclick='showNewRevewerGroupModalPanelNew(
    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Id")%>,
    <%#HttpUtility.HtmlEncode((string)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name"))%>);
    return false;' />
```

This code is probably evaluating to

```
onclick='ShowNewRevewerGroupModalPanelNew(someId, someName); return false;'
```

What you want to do is change your quotation marks on the outside and add singles to the inside:

```
onclick="showNewRevewerGroupModalPanelNew(
    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Id")%>,
    '<%#HttpUtility.HtmlEncode((string)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name"))%>');
    return false;" />
```

This should generate something closer to:

```
onclick="ShowNewRevewerGroupModalPanelNew(someId, 'someName'); return false;"
```

.Net complains when you attempt to surround a databinding like that with double quotes.

Comment: Thanks! This took me 3 hours until I asked this question.